# How to access individual item in a list view to update a progress bar indicator

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a Listview.builder list that creates a list of video files that can be played from a network URL.  I give the user an option to download each individual video to their local device.  This works fine and I can store the progress percentage in a variable.  How can I access an individual item in the list view so that I can add a progress bar indicator?  Currently, if I try and update one of the items in the builder, it updates every item..

```
Container BuildVideoList() {
    if (result == false) {
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            height: 50.0,
            width: 50.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _videos.length,
        itemBuilder: _buildItemsForListView,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItemsForListView(BuildContext context, int index) {
    var downloadText = Text('Download $progressString');
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) {
                return HitomiVideoPlayer(
                    videoKey: _videos[index].videoId,
                    title: _videos[index].title);
              }));
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Image.network(_videos[index].image),
            ),
          ),
          Text(_videos[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(_videos[index].description,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              downloadFile(
                  title: _videos[index].title,
                  description: _videos[index].description,
                  image: _videos[index].image,
                  videoID: _videos[index].videoId);
            },
            child: downloadText,
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              addInfo();
            },
            child: Text('Add Info'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: if `_videos[index]` this gives you an instance of a Video Model object, you should add a progress value variable in the model itself. Update that value according to it's respective progress and Use that value to show progress in the list's item. Just like the `title` or `image` that you are already using.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Thank you very much, worked perfectly.  You have deepened my understanding of Dart and Flutter:)